# How To call Lua function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, lua

I use "lua.vm.js" to develop with lua in web client side.

I want to know how can i call a Lua function from js script.

```
var element = document.getElementById("myBtn")
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){ /*call here Lua function*/ });
```

Comment: I doubt that you found nothing on the internet.
the lua.vm.js webpage evengives an example...

Comment: The is a [workaround](http://pastebin.com/ck1rmRmK)

Answer (score 3):

**Method #1**
Manipulate JavaScript objects from inside Lua code:

```
<script src="lua.vm.js"></script>
<script type="text/lua">
    function YourLuaFunction()
       -- your Lua code is here
    end
</script>

<button id="MyBtn">Lua inside</button>
<script type="text/lua">
    js.global.document:getElementById("MyBtn"):addEventListener("click", YourLuaFunction);
</script>
```

---

**Method #2**
Use `L.execute(code)` to execute Lua code from JS:

Short example:
`element.addEventListener("click", function(){ L.execute('YourLuaFunction()'); });`

Long example:

```
<script src="lua.vm.js"></script>
<script> 
   function executeLua(code) { 
      try { L.execute(code); } catch(e) { alert(e.toString()); } 
   } 
</script>
<script type="text/lua">
      function YourLuaFunction()
         -- your Lua code is here
      end
</script>

<button onclick="executeLua('YourLuaFunction()')">Exec Lua code</button>
```